# Banco de dados H2 no Cronapp

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, ide, cloud

Recebi a seguinte mensagem ao tentar publicar a aplicação no CronApp:
"Seu projeto utiliza um banco de dados H2. Os dados persistidos nesse tipo de banco poderão ser perdidos, devido à arquitetura distribuída e sem estado do cloud. Sugerimos usar outro tipo de banco de dados. Mesmo assim deseja continuar?"
Como posso criar outro tipo de banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

O ambiente de desenvolvimento do CronApp utiliza o banco de dados do tipo H2, que utiliza memória para armazenamento em disco. Os containers onde são publicadas as aplicações no CronApp não possuem armazenamento em disco.

Dessa forma, quando sua aplicação for publicada, você poderá até utilizar o banco H2 e tudo irá funcionar inclusive a gravação e leitura de dados, porém ao parar a aplicação o container será desligado, e quando for novamente iniciado, os dados terão desaparecido, pois só estavam na memória do container inicial, que foi desligado. 
Para criar um banco de dados na nuvem, utilizando o CronApp IDE siga os passos:

1. Clicar em Fonte de Dados (abre a aba )
2. Clicar no botão
3. Clicar no link
4. Você é redirecionado para o console que apresenta a lista de bancos
   disponíveis
5. Clicar no botão [+] para adicionar
6. Informar o nome do novo banco de dados
7. O nome do banco criado passa a aparecer na lista
8. Voltar para a aba Fonte de Dados, clicando sobre ela
9. Selecionar da lista de bancos de dados na nuvem o nome do banco criado
10. Clicar em
11. Banco de dados é criado e aparece na lista de fontes de dados do
     projeto

Note que, além de criar o banco de dados na nuvem, você precisa ajustar a sua aplicação para usar a nova fonte de dados criada. Se você está utilizando o mecanismo de geração de camada de persistência através do diagrama, entre no diagrama e altere a fonte de dados selecionando da lista disponível a nova fonte de dados que corresponde ao seu banco de dados na nuvem recém criado.
Você vai encontrar mais informações em: https://docs.cronapp.io/display/CRON2/Bancos+de+dados+na+Nuvem